# Swift how best advance in a nested JSON

Tags: json, swift

I'm currently working on an application that asks the user questions. The questions are in a JSON with nested answers and nested next questions

[image]

What would be the best way to advance in this JSON as the user answers questions? I know that it is a very open question, but a starting point would be appreciated. I just don't see `myJson["question"][0]["answers"]...` being a proper way to do it. But correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Can you control the way the JSON is returned? as in do you have control of the API?

Comment: @Scriptable no I do not have control over the JSON or the API. It has been this way since the Android team uses it in this manner and I have to hook in.

Comment: you can try nested structs

Comment: @SergioTrejo Correct me if I'm wrong, but since the JSON depth is unknown, I don't know if that is the best option